# WCF Thread Sleep

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows service that starts a host for a WCF service. I have an interface defining the ServiceContract and OperationContracts. There is a class that implements this interface. The `ServiceBehavior` attribute is `PerSession`. As I understand, each session get its own class instance on the WCF service.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = ServiceModel.InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class WCFServiceImplementation : WCFServiceInterface
{

}
```

Now some where in my `WCFServiceImplementation` I am calling `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` (there are some race conditions). My question - can the service still be called by other clients while the thread is in sleep? I am not very familiar with threading, does each class instance run on its own separate thread with WCF services.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is never the answer to race conditions...

Comment: @jeroenh I would have liked to avoid, but I need to communicate with an external application which is not controlled by my code.

Comment: Can you add some detail about your communication with your 3rd party app, perhaps we can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the service can still be called by other clients because they will be on other sessions.