# Polling a WCF service method in a blocking call within a another WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, task, blocking

**Update:**

**The issue has been resolved. Both pieces of code actually work. An underlying issue was causing failure.**

---

I am not much of a threading expert but this is my scenario.

I have two `WCF` services (`ServiceA` and `ServiceB`)

`ServiceA` must

1. poll `ServiceB` every second or configured interval,
2. for a certain status,
3. blocking until `ServiceB` retuns the desired status
4. ServiceA method then proceeds to its next action

Focusing on the implementation of `Service A`to achieve the requirement, and assuming I am using a generated service reference for `Service B`, cleanly disposing and closing, with interfaces defined:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
   public ResultObject ServiceAMethod()
   {
       var serviceBClient = new ServiceBReference.ServiceBClient();
       //do sometthing
       //call ServiceB every 1second until the status changes or a WCF timeout ends the process
       return new ResultObject{/*set whatever properties need to be set*/}
    }
}
```

What I have tried and does not block:

**Attempt 1**

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
   public ResultObject ServiceAMethod()
   {
        var serviceBClient = new ServiceBReference.ServiceBClient();
        //do sometthing
        //call ServiceB every 1second until the status changes or a WCF timeout ends the process

        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        SomeStatusEnum status;
        int pollingInterval = 1000;
        var listener = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            status = serviceBClient.GetStatus();
            while (status != SomeStatusEnum.Approved)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval);
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;

                status = serviceBClient.GetStatus();
            }
        }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
       return new ResultObject{/*set whatever properties need to be set determined by status*/}
    }
}
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
   public ResultObject ServiceAMethod()
   {
        var serviceBClient = new ServiceBReference.ServiceBClient();
        //do sometthing
        //call ServiceB every 1second until the status changes or a WCF timeout ends the process

        SomeStatusEnum status;
        int pollingInterval = 1000;

        status = serviceBClient.GetStatus();
        while (status == SomeStatusEnum.Approved)
        {
            status = serviceBClient.GetStatus();;
            if (status != SomeStatusEnum.Approved)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval);
        }
       return new ResultObject{/*set whatever properties need to be set determined by status*/}
    }
}
```

**In both cases, status is never set to the expected value. What could I be doing wrong? Is there behavior associated with WCF applications that could be causing this?**

**My sources**:

1. [Should I always use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356139/should-i-always-use-task-delay-instead-of-thread-sleep)
2. [WCF Thread Sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644132/wcf-thread-sleep)
3. [C# error System.NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929016/c-sharp-error-system-nullreferenceexception)
4. [Calling a method every x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019433/calling-a-method-every-x-minutes)
5. [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Comment: Why cant the call to ServiceB be a Blocking (Synchronous) call. Anyways you need to make ServiceA wait until result appears. Is ServiceB PerInstance, PerCall or Singleton -- put some logs in ServiceB method call to see what status is being returned.

Comment: If its synchronous, how would this be done @PrateekShrivastava?

Comment: When the call to ServiceB is synchronous. GetStatus() would be blocked until the correct status is returned. So in effect ServiceA is waiting for response from ServiceB.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Both pieces of code actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both pieces of code actually work.

Can delete the question, but choosing to leave it for reference purposes, as it also includes references that may assist the next person.